# Thread.sleep causing unexpected behavior in ExecutorService loop

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, executorservice

In below test class just "before" is outputted.

But if I removed Thread.sleep the following is outputted :

```
before
after
before
after
before
after
before
after
before
after
before
after
before
after
before
after
before
after
before
after
```

Which is what I expect.

When I use Thread.sleep I think that there should be a 1000ms delay between each output of

```
before
after
```

Why is this not occuring & how can the code be amended so that the generated output is same regardless of calling sleep or not ?

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RunExecutorTest {

    private ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    private class RunTest implements Runnable {
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("before");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("after");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testRun() {

        Runnable r = new RunTest();

        for(int counter = 0; counter < 10; ++counter) {  
            executor.execute(r);
        }
    }

}
```

Update from reading comment below "@user470184 It doesn't work in junit test cases because Junit kills all threads when the main thread completes. – Sotirios Delimanolis" if I add

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

at the end of test method then it works as expected.

Comment: _In below test class just "before" is outputted._ Are you sure? It works for me.

Comment: I have a 1 sec delay between each `println()`, but the delay is between `before` and `after`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "the delay is between before and after" is that not same as code I posted ?

Comment: You can also see this output on [IDEOne](http://ideone.com/3jeCar), you can see all the desired output

Comment: @BackSlash it does behave as expected when I use a standalone class as in ideone.com/3jeCar . But it does not work when using within a junit test class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I use Thread.sleep I think that there should be a 1000ms delay
>   between each output of
>
> before 
>   after
>
> Why is this not occuring & how can the code be amended so
>   that the generated output is same regardless of calling sleep or not ?

The delay is clearly between `before` and `after`, not between each iteration of those

```
System.out.println("before");

try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("after");
```

yielding

```
before
...1000 millis
after
before
...1000 millis
after
```

Perhaps I've misunderstood your question.

You **do** have a Thread pool of 1 thread.

```
private ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

All of this will be output sequentially.

---

As for why it's failing with JUnit, JUnit kills all threads when its main Thread completes execution. You cannot really control this (short of implementing your own wait mechanism).

Comment: it does behave as expected when I use a standalone class as in http://ideone.com/3jeCar . But it does not work when using within a junit test class

Comment: @user470184 It doesn't work in junit test cases because Junit kills all threads when the main thread completes.

Comment: @user470184 for the junit case, do a .shutdown() on the Executor after the loop which submit the tasks, then a .awaitTermination(). This will run all the tasks, and block until they've finished